# PHP7, PDO, DBLIB not returns result of stored procedures

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am not able to get the output from Stored Procedure in PHP. My variable `$value` does not change. I have set attribute bind to `PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT`. Correct response is `int` from the procedure.

SQL code inside the procedure runs correctly. What is wrong?

My environment:

- PHP 7.0.15
- FreeTDS 0.91
- MSSQL 2012 SP1

**SQL Procedure:**

```
DECLARE @Aaa int

EXECUTE [sp_insert_org] 
@Aaa = @Aaa OUTPUT

SELECT  @Aaa
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$value = 'hello';

$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4); 
$sth->execute();

var_export($value);
```

**Result:**

```
'hello'
```

Comment: After `$sth->execute()`, can you add `$sth->closeCursor()` and try to echo the variable?

Comment: After add function closeCursor() is this same result *hello*.

Comment: Try to refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982466/executing-a-stored-procedure-with-pdo-sqlsrv), it might help. The answer that works uses `$sth->fetch()` before echoing out the variable.

Comment: you should also always put "set nocount on" as the first statement in every stored procedure in sql server. Not that it will fix this problem but it is a best practice

Comment: Really did not fix it, but thanks.